# TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python-2.7, keras, conv-neural-network

l trained a cnn using keras,

```
%%time
scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

l got the following results

```
acc: 67.62%
CPU times: user 1.66 s, sys: 836 ms, total: 2.49 s
Wall time: 447 ms
```

l want to use to use a function show_failures() to inspect failures in more detail. For example, here are failures in which the true class was "6".

after doing prediction   using

```
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
```

l defined  :

```
def show_failures(predictions, trueclass=None, predictedclass=None, maxtoshow=10):
    rounded = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
    errors = rounded!=y_test
    print('Showing max', maxtoshow, 'first failures. '
          'The predicted class is shown first and the correct class in parenthesis.')
    ii = 0
    plt.figure(figsize=(maxtoshow, 1))
    for i in range(X_test.shape[0]):
        if ii>=maxtoshow:
            break
        if errors[i]:
            if trueclass is not None and y_test[i] != trueclass:
                continue
            if predictedclass is not None and predictions[i] != predictedclass:
                continue
            plt.subplot(1, maxtoshow, ii+1)
            plt.axis('off')
            if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th':
                plt.imshow(X_test[i,0,:,:], cmap="gray")
            else:
                plt.imshow(X_test[i,:,:,0], cmap="gray")
            plt.title("%d (%d)" % (rounded[i], y_test[i]))
            ii = ii + 1
```

l got the following error :

```
Showing max 10 first failures. The predicted class is shown first and the correct class in parenthesis.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-67c05a85372a> in <module>()
      1 predictions = model.predict(x_test)
      2 
----> 3 show_failures(predictions)

<ipython-input-77-878906bfc03b> in show_failures(predictions, trueclass, predictedclass, maxtoshow)
      9         if ii>=maxtoshow:
     10             break
---> 11         if errors[i]:
     12             if trueclass is not None and y_test[i] != trueclass:
     13                 continue

TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7f9b8af32150>
```

Comment: Before line 11, try `print errors`, what does it show?

Comment: l got the same error at print(errors[i])

Comment: No, don't print errors[i], before line 11, `print errors`

Comment: ok l tried print(errors) ; lt doesn't print errors :   Showing max 10 first failures. The predicted class is shown first and the correct class in parenthesis.
True

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

     11         print(errors)
---> 12         if errors[i]:
     13             if trueclass is not None and y_test[i] != trueclass:
     14                 continue

TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: I found your problem `errors = rounded!=y_test`, errors is actually a boolean and you cannot do errors[i]

Comment: thank you it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do an **EXCLUSIVE OR** of your rounded and y_test to build error. The simplest way (without any libraries) is:

```
errors = [x!=y for x, y in zip(rounded, y_test)]
```